# Database Management

Tags: database

I want to learn about triggers, viewer in SQL ?
I also would like to learn some Advanced database management concepts ?
would someone give me a clue about a Text that i can learn it individually ?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are somewhat database specific.  Meaning that triggers and database management will be somewhat different for MySQL, Oracle, and DB2.

The advantage of learning about MySQL is that you can practice on your own machine.

The advantage of learning about Oracle and DB2 is that people will pay you based on your knowledge and ability.

Comment: You can learn Oracle and DB2 on your own machine as well - they have free versions for evaluation and learning. And don't forget PostgreSQL...

Comment: Thanks for the additional information.  I wonder if the free versions of Oracle or DB2 allow you to practice database management?

Answer (score 0):

Database Management has evolved dramatically over the last decade or so. For example, the Oracle Autonomous Database aims to eliminate the need to perform mundane database “management” tasks, so DBAs can now focus on greater value activities such as fleet management and getting value out of data through analytics and machine learning, integration, and leveraging converged database features and capabilities for applications etc. This increases an Oracle DBA productivity and value to the organization, very substantially.

The Oracle Autonomous Database is self-driving, self-securing, and self-repairing. You can learn more about Oracle Autonomous Database at https://www.oracle.com/autonomous-database/

Oracle is also currently (in 2021) offering free training and certification for Oracle Autonomous Database.

BTW, to answer the other part of your question - you can learn about TRIGGERS from the Oracle documentation. Please refer to the Using Triggers section in the 2 Day Developer's Guide to start with - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/tdddg/using-triggers.html#GUID-3744214A-861D-4C59-AD2D-95840B5B0871